# How to correctly fetch data from online API on page reload?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui, viewmodel

I'm building a MAUI app and am trying to figure out the correct and recommended way to fetch data from the internet when I open/reopen a XAML page.

I found advice to use code-behind's methods:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    // Code to execute when the page appears
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    // Code to execute when the page disappears
}
```

...but I would like to do it in the ViewModel of my page. What's the right way?

Comment: There is no "right" way.  If you want the code to execute in the VM, you can create a public method to do what, and then call it from the code-behind.

Comment: Is it safe to "just" call it or should I eg. Invoke or use a Dispatcher?

Comment: Just call it and see what happens. It's better to try and learn something than just asking for recommendations that might not even apply to your specific situation. Generally, you can call any ViewModel code from the View. However, since API calls might take some time, the operation should run asynchronously in order to not block the UI. Any business logic (and usually also API calls) belong into the ViewModel, so maybe expose a method like `public async Task LoadDataFromApiAsync()` and `await` that in the code-behind of your View. `OnAppearing()` might not always be the right place, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

A simple method is to call the public method or property of the View Model of current page.

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class TestPage : BasePage
{
    TestViewModel viewModel;

    public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

          viewModel = new TestViewModel();
          BindingContext = viewModel;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        (BindingContext as TestViewModel).DoSomething();

        //viewModel.DoSomething();

    }
}
```

And if you define the viewmodel in `YourPage.xaml.cs`, you can also trigger the method of view model as follows:

```
TestViewModel viewModel;

public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

      viewModel = new TestViewModel();
      BindingContext = viewModel;
}
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    //call method of viewmodel
    viewModel.DoSomething();

}
```

Another way is to create `BaseViewModel` and `BasePage` for your app.

Please follow the following steps:

1.install nuget [CommunityToolkit.MVVM](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/)

2.create class `BasePage` as follows:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        public BasePage()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "Back");

            Loaded += OnLoaded;
            Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        }

        void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetupBinding(BindingContext);
        }

        void OnUnloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TearDownBinding(BindingContext);
        }

        protected void SetupBinding(object bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext is BaseViewModel vm)
            {
                vm.DoDisplayAlert += OnDisplayAlert;
                vm.DoNavigate += OnNavigate;
                vm.OnAppearing();
            }
        }

        protected void TearDownBinding(object bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext is BaseViewModel vm)
            {
                vm.OnDisappearing();
                vm.DoDisplayAlert -= OnDisplayAlert;
                vm.DoNavigate -= OnNavigate;
            }
        }

        Task OnDisplayAlert(string message)
        {
            return DisplayAlert(Title, message, "OK");
        }

        Task OnNavigate(BaseViewModel vm, bool showModal)
        {
            var name = vm.GetType().Name;
            name = name.Replace("ViewModel", "Page", StringComparison.Ordinal);

            var ns = GetType().Namespace;
            var pageType = Type.GetType($"{ns}.{name}");

            var page = (BasePage)Activator.CreateInstance(pageType);
            page.BindingContext = vm;

            return showModal
                ? Navigation.PushModalAsync(page)
                : Navigation.PushAsync(page);
        }
    }
```

3.create `BaseViewModel.cs`,just as follows:

```
 public class BaseViewModel: ObservableObject
    {
/*        bool isBusy;

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get => isBusy;
            set => SetProperty(ref isBusy, value, onChanged: () => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsNotBusy)));
        }*/

        public virtual void OnAppearing()
        {
        }

        public virtual void OnDisappearing()
        {
        }

        internal event Func<string, Task> DoDisplayAlert;

        internal event Func<BaseViewModel, bool, Task> DoNavigate;

        public Task DisplayAlertAsync(string message)
        {
            return DoDisplayAlert?.Invoke(message) ?? Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task NavigateAsync(BaseViewModel vm, bool showModal = false)
        {
            return DoNavigate?.Invoke(vm, showModal) ?? Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

3.create `TestViewModel.cs`

```
public class TestViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public override void OnAppearing()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------do something when the page appears");

        base.OnAppearing();
    }


    public override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------do something when the page disappears");

        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
}
```

4.create a `TestPage.xaml` which extends `BasePage` and set `BindingContext`  to `TestViewModel.cs` for this page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<views:BasePage
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiApp129.Pages"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MauiApp129.ViewModels"
             Title="TestPage"
             x:Class="MauiApp129.Pages.TestPage"
             >

    <views:BasePage.BindingContext>
        <viewmodels:TestViewModel></viewmodels:TestViewModel>
    </views:BasePage.BindingContext>
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</views:BasePage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage : BasePage
{
      public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

}
```

5.if you want to navigate to `TestPage`,you can use the following code:

```
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TestPage)));

    }
```

**Note:**

You can also refer to the official sample: [.NET MAUI - Platform integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/dotnet/maui-samples/platformintegration-essentials/) which also use the `BasePage` and `BaseViewModel` this way.

Comment: Wow, this seems like a huge overkill to just make a call to the web backend. I thought there would be a prepared method to override or something. Blazor seems a lot easier from this point of view - you just add the one line in the page's code and it works on every reopening. Ehhh...

Comment: Another simple method is to call the public method of the View Model . You can check the update part of my answer. :)